# How to prevent empty context menu from showing in GXT

Tags: java, gwt, contextmenu, gxt

I have a TreePanel which shows different kind of objects hierarchically. Region, City, Location...

I want to be able to show different context menu items in different levels. For example: miR for Region, miC for City, miL for Location...
I used this snipped to achieve that dynamic structure:

```
    contextMenu.addListener(Events.BeforeShow, new Listener<MenuEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(MenuEvent be) {
            //First make all menu items invisible
            List<Component> menuItems = contextMenu.getItems();
            for (Component c : menuItems) {
                c.setVisible(false);
            }               

            //And make apprepriate menu items visible
            TopologyTreeElement s = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (s instanceof TopologyTreeElement.Region) {
                miR.setVisible(true);
            }
            if (s instanceof TopologyTreeElement.City) {
                miC.setVisible(true);
            }                                   
        }
    });
```

But, in any level if all of the items are invisible, it shows an empty box. I want it not to show the menu totally. I tried adding this code snippet to the method, but it gave no help.

```
            //Do not show menu if no menu item is invisible     
            boolean isMenuShouldBeVisible = miC.isVisible() || miR.isVisible();
            if (!isMenuShouldBeVisible) {
                be.preventDefault();
                be.stopEvent();
            }
```

Anyone can suggest a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are listening to the `BeforeShow` event, you are allowed to cancel the event and stop the actual `Show` event from happening. Check to see if all items are invisible, and if so, call `be.setCancelled(true)`.

Any event that starts in `Before` can be used to cancel the later event - this is why these before- events exist at all.